# Resizing Page to fit window

Tags: html, css, height, width

I have built my website with VS Code then exported it to Htdocs in Xampp to connect to databases

When I have moved it over the page is oversized and doesn't scale anymore for different sized screens (as long as it scales to computer/laptop screens then that's fine).

I'm not completely new to this coding and have tried contstraint, having a fixed zoom to try cheat the system, wrappers, changing the scale in the meta, changing from px to % then back again, nothing seems to work basically.

The code is a bit messy at the moment so sorry about that but can anyone see why the page is stupidly big?

This has happened on all pages and only layout.css is linked to every page so im guessing its something in there.

I've attached the index.html and the layout.css - the java and php have no impact on the sizings just aids transitions of popups.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" onmouseout = "mouseOutOfWindow()">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Best Cars Ltd. | Home</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./images/icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/landing.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/search.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/aside.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/popup.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/chat.css">
    
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <script src="./path/to/jquery.prevent-duplicate-submit.js"></script>


   
</head>
<body id="body" style=" clear:both; width: 1280px;">
    
  <div id="bigboy-contain">
       
    <header class="header">

        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="./Pages/Search.html">Search</a>
            <a href="./Pages/directions.html">Find Us</a>
            <a href="./Pages/contactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
            <a href="./Pages/FAQ.html">FAQ's</a>
            <a href="./Pages/aboutUs.html">About Us</a>
          </div>
          
         

        <button id="navButt" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">
            <img src="./images/nav.png" alt="Nav Image">
        </button>
        
      <div class="center"> <a href="./index.html"><img src="./images/icon.png" alt="" class="logo"> </a></div>
          
      <div class="containerlog">
        <a href="../team04/Pages/login.html" class="login" class="cursor">Login | Sign Up</a>
      </div>

    </header>
    
    

    <main id="main">

        <div class="carsearch">
            <p>SEARCH FOR YOUR NEXT CAR!</p>
        </div>

        <div class="carousell">
            <div class="outlining">
                <p class="title">New Car Deals of the Week</p>
                <div class="slideshow-container">

                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
                    <img src="./images/skoda.png" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="text">New SKODA Deals</div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
                    <img src="./images/nissan.png" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="text">New Nissan Deals</div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
                    <img src="./images/peugeot.png" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="text">New Peugeot Deals</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
                        <img src="./images/audi.png" style="width:100%">
                        <div class="text">New Audi Deals</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
                        <img src="./images/MOKKA.png" style="width:100%">
                        <div class="text">New Vauxhall Mokka Deals</div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
                    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
                    
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    
                    <div style="text-align:center">
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
                    </div>
            </div>   
        </div>

        <div class="aside">
            <div class="maps">
              <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir//University+of+Derby,+Kedleston+Rd,+Derby+DE22+1GB/@52.9378882,-2.7166588,9z/data=!4m9!4m8!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x4879f14915620351:0xf8c8c49092cfd499!2m2!1d-1.4971764!2d52.9378882!3e0">  <img src="./images/maps.png" alt=""> </a>
            </div>

            <div class="phoneback">
                <p class="title-phone">Request Callback?</p>

                <form onsubmit="myFunction8()">
                    <input type="text" name="first name" id="f-name" placeholder="First Name">

                    <input type="text" name="Surname" id="s-name" placeholder="Surname">

                    <input type="text" name="Phone Number" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">

                    <input type="text" name="Email Address" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">

                    <input type="text" name="Message" id="message" placeholder="Message...">

                    
                    
                    <input class="callback-submit" value="SUBMIT" type="submit">
                        
                    
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="search">
        <form href="./Pages/Search.html">
            <p class="floating">New Cars</p>
            <input type="radio" name="Cars" value="" class="radio">
            <p class="floating2">Used Cars</p>
            <input type="radio"  name="Cars" value="" class="radio">
        </form>

        
        <form name="form1" id="form1" href="./Pages/Search.html" method="post" class="floating">
            <select name="cars" id="cars">
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Make</option>
                <option value='Abarth'>Abarth</option> 
                <option value='Alfa Romeo'>Alfa Romeo</option> 
                <option value='Aston Martin'>Aston Martin</option> 
                <option value='Audi '>Audi</option> 
                <option value='Bentley'>Bentley</option> 
                <option value='BMW'>BMW</option> 
                <option value='Bugatti'>Bugatti</option> 
                <option value='Cadillac'>Cadillac</option> 
                <option value='Chevrolet'>Chevrolet</option> 
                <option value='Chrysler'>Chrysler</option> 
                <option value='Citroën'>Citroën</option> 
                <option value='Dacia'>Dacia</option> 
                <option value='Daewoo'>Daewoo</option> 
                <option value='Daihatsu'>Daihatsu</option> 
                <option value='Dodge'>Dodge</option> 
                <option value='DS'>DS</option> 
                <option value='Ferrari'>Ferrari</option> 
                <option value='Fiat'>Fiat</option> 
                <option value='Ford'>Ford</option> 
                <option value='Honda'>Honda</option> 
                <option value='Hummer'>Hummer</option>
                <option value='Hyundai'>Hyundai</option>
                <option value='Infiniti'>Infiniti</option>
                <option value='Iveco'>Iveco</option>
                <option value='Jaguar'>Jaguar</option> 
                <option value='Jeep'>Jeep</option> 
                <option value='Kia'>Kia</option> 
                <option value='KTM'>KTM</option> 
                <option value='Lada'>Lada</option> 
                <option value='Lamborghini'>Lamborghini</option> 
                <option value='Lancia'>Lancia</option> 
                <option value='Land Rover'>Land Rover</option> 
                <option value='Lexus'>Lexus</option> 
                <option value='Lotus'>Lotus</option> 
                <option value='Maserati '>Maserati</option> 
                <option value='Maybach'>Maybach</option> 
                <option value='Mazda'>Mazda</option> 
                <option value='McLaren'>McLaren</option> 
                <option value='Mercedes-Benz'>Mercedes-Benz</option> 
                <option value='MG'>MG</option> 
                <option value='Mini'>Mini</option> 
                <option value='Mitsubishi'>Mitsubishi</option> 
                <option value='Morgan'>Morgan</option> 
                <option value='Nissan'>Nissan</option> 
                <option value='Opel'>Opel</option> 
                <option value='Peugeot'>Peugeot</option> 
                <option value='Porsche'>Porsche</option> 
                <option value='Renault'>Renault</option> 
                <option value='Rolls-Royce'>Rolls-Royce</option> 
                <option value='Rover'>Rover</option> 
                <option value='Saab'>Saab</option> 
                <option value='Seat'>Seat</option> 
                <option value='Skoda'>Skoda</option> 
                <option value='Smart'>Smart</option> 
                <option value='SsangYong'>SsangYong</option> 
                <option value='Subaru'>Subaru</option> 
                <option value='Suzuki'>Suzuki</option> 
                <option value='Tesla'>Tesla</option> 
                <option value='Toyota'>Toyota</option> 
                <option value='Volkswagen'>Volkswagen</option> 
                <option value='Volvo'>Volvo</option>
            </select>
            
           <input type="search" id="model" name="model" placeholder="Model">
        
           <div class="range">
            <div class="range-slider">
              <span class="range-selected"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="range-input">
              <input type="range" class="min" min="0" max="100000" value="300" step="10">
              <input type="range" class="max" min="0" max="100000" value="700" step="10">
            </div>
            <div class="range-price">      
              <label for="min">Min</label>
              <input type="number" name="min" value="300" id="box-sizing">      
              <label for="max">Max</label>
              <input type="number" name="max" value="700" id="box-sizing">      
            </div>
          </div>  

          <div class="line"></div>
         
          <div>
          <p class="breaker">Choose Vehicle Type</p>
        </div>

          <div class="types">
            <div class="vehicle-types" id="white" onclick="myFunction()">
                <div class="vehicle-image"><img src="./images/sports.png" alt="sports car"> </div>
                <p class="vehicle-label">Sports</p>
            </div>

            <div class="vehicle-types" id="white1" onclick="myFunction1()">
                <div class="vehicle-image2"><img src="./images/pickup.png" alt="Pickup car"> </div>
                <p class="vehicle-label">Pickup</p>
            </div>

            <div class="vehicle-types" id="white2" onclick="myFunction2()">
                <div class="vehicle-image4"><img src="./images/hatchback.png" alt="Hatchback car"> </div>
                <p class="vehicle-label">Hatchback</p>
            </div>

            <div class="vehicle-types" id="white3" onclick="myFunction3()">
                <div class="vehicle-image"><img src="./images/covertible.png" alt="Convertible car"> </div>
                <p class="vehicle-label">Convertible</p>
            </div>

            <div class="vehicle-types" id="white4" onclick="myFunction4()">
                <div class="vehicle-image3"><img src="./images/4x4.png" alt="4x4 car"> </div>
                <p class="vehicle-label">4x4</p>
            </div>

            <div class="vehicle-types" id="white5" onclick="myFunction5()">
                <div class="vehicle-image5"><img src="./images/saloon.png" alt="SUV car"> </div>
                <p class="vehicle-label">SUV</p>
            </div>

            <div class="vehicle-types" id="white6" onclick="myFunction6()">
                <div class="vehicle-image7"><img src="./images/estate.png" alt="Saloon car" class="saloon"> </div>
                <p class="vehicle-label">Saloon</p>
            </div>

            <div class="vehicle-types" id="white7" onclick="myFunction7()">
                <div class="vehicle-image6"><img src="./images/mpv.png" alt="Estate car" > </div>
                <p class="vehicle-label">Estate</p>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="line"></div>
        </form>
        <div class="floater">
           <a href="./Pages/Search2.html"> <button class="search-button" >  S E A R C H ! </button> </a>
           </div>
        
        </div>
       

    </main>

    <footer id="footer">

        <div class="footerContainer">

            <a href="./Pages/aboutUs.html" class="footerButt2">About Us</a>

            <p class="footerButtSpace">|</p>

            <a href="./Pages/contactUs.html" class="footerButt"> Contact Us</a>

            <p class="footerButtSpace">|</p>

            <a href="./Pages/FAQ.html" class="footerButt">FAQ's</a>

        </div>
   
    </footer>
  </div>  

    <div id="popup" class="popup2" style="background-image: url(/team04/images/Popup-Background.png);">
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"></button>

        <h1 class="display-3">SIGN UP TO OUR NEWSLETTER!</h1>

<form action="/team04/PHP/insert.php" method="post" >

        <input name="First_Name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="newsFName" >

        <input name="Surname" type="text" placeholder="Surname" class="newsSName" >

        <input name="Email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="newsEmail" >
    
        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="PopupSubmit" class="prevent" >SUBMIT</button>
      </form>
        

          <p class="popupText">Get Personalised offers and exclusive content!</p>

        <p class="popupText2">Get a 5% discount code on signing up!</p>

        <p class="popupText">

            <a id="reset_btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">CLOSE</a>
        </p>
    </div>


    <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()"><img src="./images/chat.png" alt="live chat icon" class="chatIcon"></button>

<div class="chat-popup" id="myForm1">
  <form action="./Pages/livechat.html" class="form-container">
    <h1>Chat</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="headingtext">
    <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Surname" id="headingtext">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="headingtext">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Start Chat</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </form>
</div>
</body>

<script src="./JavaScript/nav.js"></script>
<script src="./JavaScript/search.js"></script>
<script src="./JavaScript/carousell.js"></script>
<script src="./JavaScript/popup.js"></script>
<script src="./JavaScript/chat.js"></script>
<script src="./JavaScript/message.js"></script>


</html>

<div id="popup" class="popup2">
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"></button>

  <h1 class="display-3">SIGN UP TO OUR NEWSLETTER!</h1>

<form id="myForm" action="/path/to/endpoint/">

  <input name="First_Name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="newsFName" >

  <input name="Surname" type="text" placeholder="Surname" class="newsSName" >

  <input name="Email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="newsEmail" >
</form>
  <button onclick="SubForm()" class="PopupSubmit" class="prevent" >SUBMIT</button>

    <p class="popupText">Get Personalised offers and exclusive content!</p>

  <p class="popupText2">Get a 5% discount code on signing up!</p>

  <p class="popupText">

      <a id="reset_btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">CLOSE</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(87, 86, 86);
    float: left;
}

#navButt {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-color: rgb(74, 74, 74);
}

#navButt:hover {
    background-color: rgb(74, 74, 74);
}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

.logo {
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 0%;
}

.containerlog {
    width: 200px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -125px;
    padding-top: 35px;
}

.login {
    float: right;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main {
    background-color: #818181;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#footer {
    float: left;
    background-color: rgb(87, 86, 86);
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}

.footerContainer {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.footerButt {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
}

.footerButt2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 25px;
    float: left;
}

.footerButtSpace {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    float: left;
}

#body {
    background-color: rgb(87, 86, 86);
    max-width: 1920px;
}

.cursor:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

head {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.bigboy-contain {
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've tried changing the parameters of the body, the html, all the divs - i have tried putting the whole page within a div with max width and max height and overflow hidden and it still is big with scrollbars.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mre] that illustrates the issue for faster troubleshooting

Comment: Removing or changing this ```style=" clear:both; width: 1280px;"``` in the body may somehow fixed your problem.

Comment: No adding or changing that doesn't work - I believe it might be to do with the "main" section as if i delete all content from the main section it sizes correctly - i just can't find the aspect that is wrong within main.